# Is there a way to use default "icons" in ckeditor plugins?

Tags: ckeditor

I did a plugin that basically allows to create link with some business logic (People enters an id and a link is magically created for them). So I can specify an icon for it no problem there but I love the default "link" icons that comes with the monoo skins...

Is there a way to simply (re)use it ?

Just to make sure it's clear, I'm talking about the icons.png sprite that includes the main "toolbar" icon

Comment: So basically you want to re-use that default icon for link button with your custom button?

Comment: Yes, hmmm I guess the question isn't clear enough... How would your rephrase it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets say your plugin is called 'newlink'.

You should add to the editor.css of your current skin a css rule like:

```
a.cke_button .cke_button__newlink_icon{

    background : url(icons.png) 0 -1248px no-repeat;    

}
```

(that specific coords are in fact the ones for the link icon of the **moono** 'icons.png' theme. Other themes may have another, or even another path to the icons file).